# このサイトの翻訳メッセージのライセンスは何ですか？

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, ライセンス

このサイトの日本語化は、[transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/public/)でメッセージの翻訳作業が行なわれており、ユーザーの協力も受け付けていますが、ここで作成されている翻訳メッセージファイルのライセンスは何でしょうか。

Comment: 個人的にも長らく気になっていたので、MSE にも投稿してみました - [How are translations of the Stack Exchange international sites submitted by community users licensed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364706)

Answer (score 4):

法務担当者に確認いたしました。翻訳された文字列はサイトのコンテンツと同じライセンスを持つこととなります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「サイトのコンテンツと同じライセンス」というのは、StackOverflow へのユーザー投稿コンテンツのライセンス、すなわち CC BY-SA 4.0 を意味しますか？

Comment: @mjy あなたは正しいです、それはcc by-saの下でライセンスされるべきです（私が間違っていなければ、現在4.0）