# このサイトの翻訳ファイルを明確に CC-BY-SA-4.0 でライセンスして欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 調査中, 翻訳, ライセンス

先日、[「このサイトの翻訳メッセージのライセンスは何ですか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3606/3054)という質問をしました。そして、Stack Exchange社内では CC-BY-SA-4.0 で扱うべきと認識している、と解釈できるコメントをいただきました。

> それはcc by-saの下でライセンスされるべきです（私が間違っていなければ、現在4.0）
> -– Nicolas Chabanovsky ([このサイトの翻訳メッセージのライセンスは何ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3606/#comment3590_3628))

しかし、このコメントを以って第三者が対象のファイルを CC-BY-SA-4.0 で扱えるかというと、それは少々難しいと思います。つきましては、一般的な形で CC-BY-SA-4.0 であると明示していただけると嬉しいです。例えば、プロジェクトサイトや関連サイト、あるいは対象ファイル自体にライセンスを表記する、ということです。

対象となるファイルは、例えば日本語版であれば、 https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/english/ からダウンロードできる、

```
for_translation_stack-overflow-ja_english_ja.json
for_use_stack-overflow-ja_english_ja.json
for_translation_xliff_stack-overflow-ja_english_ja.xlf
```

などかと思います。
以上、ご検討いただけると幸いです。

---

追記:

[help/licensing](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) および利用規約からライセンスは自明では無いか？ というご意見がありました。

しかし、第三者が翻訳ファイルを「一般にアクセス可能なユーザーによる投稿」あるいは「ユーザーがサイトに投稿した公的にアクセス可能なコンテンツ」とみなすのには障害があります。

- 翻訳作業は Transifex (あるいは traducir.win) で行なわれており、StackOverflow の各サイトへの投稿と同一視できません。
- 翻訳ファイルには「Teams」などのクローズなサービスの UI 文字列も含まれているようです。
- 翻訳ファイルの原文と翻訳の多くはユーザーでなく StackOverflow 内部の方々の作業によって作られています。
- そもそも、翻訳プロジェクトでは著作権者（翻訳に貢献したユーザーを含むと思われますが、よく解りません）が表記されておらず、CC-BY-SA-4.0 が求める「適切なクレジット」ができません。

私は、翻訳ファイルをユーザー投稿コンテンツ（からの派生？）と見なすことに反対しません。しかし、上記を踏まえると、第三者がこれを主張するのは難しく、利用規約だけを根拠にすると強弁になってしまいます。やはり、明確にライセンスしていただく必要があると考えます。

---

いただいたコメントからすると、誤解があるかも知れませんので追記します:

私の理解では、現状の翻訳ファイルは、どのような形式でもライセンスされていない（第三者に何も許可されていない）、という事です。

- CC-BY-SA-4.0 でライセンスする義務がある
- 既に CC-BY-SA-4.0 であるはずだから、明記する義務がある

などの主張をしているわけでは **ありません** 。
CC-BY-SA-4.0 にしていただけるなら嬉しいな、とお願いをしているだけです。

Comment: ページ下部にあるリンクから https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing にたどり着けたり、ヘルプページにはこの和訳である https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing があったりしますが、それでは難しいでしょうか？　投稿物の更新日によって微妙にバージョンが違うので、ページ内に正確に表示すると煩雑になるのではないかと考えています。翻訳物も「コンテンツ」なのであれば、同じ規則にしたがうのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu ユーザー投稿コンテンツと同一視する、というのは一つの有り得る考え方だと思います。
それでも、一般的な方法で明確にライセンスしていただくのがよいと考えますので、追記しました。
「バージョンが違うので、ページ内に正確に表示すると煩雑になる」という部分はよく解らなかったです。

Comment: 「明記を求めるわけではない」との事ですが、では具体的にこの提案に対してどのような対応を行うことで "解決" となりますか？単にスタッフから回答として「CC-BY-SA-4.0 でライセンスします」と言質が取れればOKという事でしょうか？

Comment: @cubick 追記が解りづらかったかも知れませんね、すいません。私は「明記を求めるわけではない」と書いていないないです。明記して欲しいです。「義務がある」と主張しているわけでは無い、という事です。