# このサイトの翻訳ファイルの著作権保持者は誰ですか？

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

このサイトや、その他の非英語版 StackOverflow の翻訳作業は、[Transifex](https://explore.transifex.com/stack-exchange/) で公開されている翻訳ファイルを元にしています。多くの人がこれらのファイルの翻訳に貢献しています。(現在は [Traducir](https://traducir.win/) 経由で作業中です)

ここで確認したいことが有ります。これらの翻訳ファイルの著作権は誰にありますか?

私が思い付く可能性は次の2つです。

- Stack Exchange 社
- Stack Exchange 社と、翻訳に貢献したユーザー

---

#### 関連質問

##### Meta Stack Exchange での同趣旨

同じ趣旨を、[Meta Stack Exchange でも質問しています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382629/who-owns-the-copyright-of-translation-files-for-internationalized-sites)。Stack Exchange 社からの反応は有りません。

なお、そこでの応答の中で、

- 質問や回答の投稿と同じルールは適用されていないこと
- 著作権保持者は、ライセンスや貢献者とは別の概念として存在するので、それらを尋ねる質問とは別であること

などを説明しています。

##### ライセンスを尋ねる質問

「 [このサイトの翻訳メッセージのライセンスは何ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3606/) 」ではライセンスを質問しています。スタッフの方からの反応はいただきましたが、Stack Exchange 社 としての答は得られていません。これは「いかなる形でもライセンスされていない」ことを示します。いわゆる「All rights reserved」です。

従業員の方が、「〜でライセンスされるはず」とか「〜でライセンスされるべきだ」と考えていても、それは「ライセンスされている」事を示しません。残念ながら、ライセンスとは契約ですので、そういう物です。

##### CC でライセンスして欲しいというお願い

上の状況を受けて、「 [このサイトの翻訳ファイルを明確に CC-BY-SA-4.0 でライセンスして欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3632/) 」ではお願いをしましたが、回答は有りません。

##### Meta Stack Exchange でのライセンスと貢献者の表示に関する質問

cubick さんが、「 [To who are translations licensed in Stack Exchange international sites that are submitted by community users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364706/) 」で質問しています。回答は有りません。