# 2023 年 5 月版の行動規範を和訳したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, 行動規範

どこかのタイミングから https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct に英語が混じるようになっていました。和訳したいです。「最後の更新：2023-05-31」となっているのでそのあたりから変わっていた模様。

https://ja.traducir.win/ で進めてもいいのですが、string の中でも重要度が高いものなので、メタで一度翻訳してから https://ja.traducir.win/ に反映するという流れにしたいです。

原文を wiki 回答として投稿しておくので、これを編集していく形で翻訳していきましょう。

Comment: ここで作業すると CC BY-SA になりますが、それは問題ないですか？

Comment: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3606/19110 を気にしてらっしゃるのだと思いますが、なにか不都合なことがありますか？

Comment: いえ、関連する事柄ですが事情は大分異なります。
一般に、UIの要素一つ一つには（直ちには）著作権が発生しないと考えて問題は無いと思います。
ですから、ここで作成されたUIの翻訳メッセージをコピペしてしまっても構わないはずです（少なくとも、直ちに著作権違反とはなりません）。
しかし、ある程度の長さが有り、思想や感情の関係するものは著作物なので、そういった物で CC BY-SA の物をコピペすると、ライセンスに従う必要が発生します。
現在、ユーザーの投稿一つ一つに投稿や編集に関わった人とライセンスが明記されていますが、行動規範でもそれが必要になってしまうかも知れない、ということです。

Comment: うーん、どこで問題になるのかがパッとは分かりませんでした。https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct のページに contributor の表示が必須になるかもしれないということをおっしゃっていますか？　個人的にはそこまで厳密になる必要はなくて、今までヘルプセンターの文字列を翻訳してきたときと同じように扱えると思うのですが。もし仮に問題になるとしても、SOja Community みたいな文字列を添えるだけで解決できそうです。

Comment: 解りました。nekketsuuuさんがStackExchange社との関係性で自信を持って作業できているという事であれば、それで結構です。
私も時間が有れば協力します。
ただ一般の話として、他者の知財をCC（他のライセンスでも同じですが）としてアップロードしてその上で作業を進めてしまうと問題に成り得るという事は気にとめておいて下さい。

Comment: Hey all. Thanks for taking the initiative on this. I'm looking into this and will have some more information hopefully by early next month.

Comment: 全てに時間がかかってしまい大変申し訳ありません。Traducir にて string をこれから特定してマークをつけてまいりますので、翻訳案を入力後に権限をお持ちの方が承認するとサイトへの反映が可能な状態となります‍♀️。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

行動規範が日本語で表示されるようになりました。翻訳の反映まで時間がかかり申し訳ありませんでした。どうぞ[こちらのリンク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)をご活用くださいませ‍♀️。

[image: 全ての人が温かく迎えられるコミュニティの行動規範]

Answer (score 3):

以下が翻訳案です。

---

## 行動規範

私たちの使命は、質の高い質問と回答のライブラリを構築することです。そして、優しさや協力、相互尊重に根ざした、全ての人が歓迎される安全なコミュニティでのコラボレーションを促進することです。

質問をするためにこのサイトを訪れた人も、知識を惜しみなく共有しに来たという人も、専門知識やアイデンティティに関わらず全ての人が温かく迎えられ参加できるコミュニティを共に作りましょう。

私たちは本行動規範を遵守し、これからも改善して行くことに全力を尽くします。スタック・オーバーフロー及び Stack Exchange ネットワーク全てのサイトに本行動規範は適用され、チーム、[モデレーター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)、そしてQ&Aサイトやチャットルームに投稿する全てのユーザーが含まれます。

### 期待される行動

以下に、Stack Exchange ネットワーク全体で一般的に適用される事項を示します。サイトによってはより厳しい要件があったり、質問/回答/コメントに対して異なるポリシーが適用される場合があります。異なる場合には各サイトポリシーに従ってください。

#### ユーザー間でのやりとり

ネットワーク上でコミュニケーションをとる際には、全てのユーザーに対して互いに思いやりと敬意を持って接することが期待されます。私たちがここにいる理由は学び合うためであり、時には誤りや誤解が生じてしまうこともあるかもしれません。コメントやその他の行為が意図せず有害であるように受け取られてしまう可能性もあります。もし有害だと思われる行為やコンテンツに遭遇した場合には、モデレーターに通報してください。モデレーターが状況を審査し、適切な措置を講じます。

#### 質問にあたって

ネットワークにアクセスするほとんどの人は、質問に対する回答を見つけるために Stack Exchange サイトへ訪れます。コミュニティがあなたの質問に適切に回答できるように、全ての新しい質問には最低限の品質基準があります。詳しくは、[「良い質問をするには？」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)。

#### 回答にあたって

コミュニティでの知識共有こそがプラットフォームの基盤です。最高品質の情報リポジトリを保証するため、ネットワーク上のすべての回答に適用される品質基準が存在します。詳しくは、[「良い回答を書くには？」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)。

#### 投票

Stack Exchange の仕組みの中核を成すのが、投票システムです。コミュニティによって選ばれた優れたコンテンツを示し、コミュニティメンバーの貢献に報いる方法、それが投票です。不適切な投票行動によってプラットフォームの信頼性が損なわれる可能性があります。投票システムの使用については、[「投票が重要なのはなぜ？」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)。不適切な投票パターンの詳細については、以下の「容認できない行為」についてのセクションをご覧ください。

#### コンテンツのキュレーション

ネットワーク上のコンテンツは、コミュニティメンバーの熱心な努力によって整えられます。コミュニティメンバーはレビューと編集を通じてコンテンツを厳選し、質問と回答を明確で関連性のある最良の状態に保ちます。[コミュニティによるコンテンツキュレーションについては「自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか？編集はどのように機能しますか？」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)。

#### コメント

コメントは通常、説明の要求、建設的な批判、関連性が低く重要ではない情報の追加などに使用されます。これらのコメントは一時的なもので、不要になった場合は自由に削除されると見なされます。[コメントの目的とそのガイドラインについて詳しくは、「どこでもコメント」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)。

### 容認できない行為

プラットフォーム全体における、容認できない行為の主な事項を以下に示します：

#### 嫌がらせ行為

嫌がらせや暴力を助長、奨励、美化、または予告するコンテンツは許可されません。また、排除や疎外する雰囲気も認められません。一般的には、投票（プラス/マイナス票やクローズ票など）やその他のキュレーション活動は不正行為とはみなされません。[詳細については、「嫌がらせ行為に関するポリシー」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/abusive-behavior)。

#### センシティブなコンテンツと画像

自殺、自傷行為、危害や残虐行為を促進、奨励、指示、または美化するコンテンツは、一切許可されません。[「センシティブなコンテンツと画像に関するポリシー」について詳しくは、こちらをお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/sensitive-content)。あなたまたは他の誰かが助けを必要としている場合は[「ユーザーが危機に陥った状況での対処法」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/self-harm)。

#### 有害な政治的コンテンツ

他人への危害を奨励したり、反社会的集団やヘイトグループの理念を支持、称賛、推進する政治的なコンテンツは許可されません。ネットワークサイトによっては、行動規範に違反しない限り、政治家やその政策、政府に対する鋭く厳しい批判（風刺的な発言を含む）を許可する場合もあります。[詳細については「有害な政治的コンテンツに関するポリシー」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/political-speech)。

#### 誤解を招く情報

個人やグループに害を及ぼすリスクを伴う、虚偽、有害、または誤解を招く情報を宣伝するコンテンツは許可されません。また、政党や政府、またはイデオロギーの利益を促進する目的で、虚偽の情報や誤解を招く情報を宣伝するコンテンツも許可されません。[詳細については「誤解を招く情報に関するポリシー」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/misleading-information)。

#### ツールの乱用

特定の対象を標的とし、コミュニティに害を及ぼしコンテンツの信頼性を損なうツールの乱用行為は許可されません。[詳細については「ツールの乱用ポリシー」をお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/disruptive-use)。

#### 不正使用

利用規約に違反するシステムの使用、またはユーザーやネットワークに不必要な混乱や損害を直接引き起こすシステムの使用は一切許可されません。[「不正使用ポリシー」について詳しくはこちらをお読みください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage)。

### 通報

誰もが協力的で敬意を持つコミュニティの構築に貢献できます。自分自身または他の人に向けられた許容できない行為を見つけた場合、[有害なコンテンツを通報してください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)。モデレーターは定期的に通報を審査します。行動規範に誠実に従わないユーザーは、アカウントの停止を含む、モデレーションチームが適切と判断した措置を受けます。

すべての措置は、モデレーターの裁量により、ケースバイケースで行われます。モデレーターの決定に満足できない場合は、[コンタクトフォームから連絡し](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)、異議を申し立てることができます。Stack Exchange 社は、全ての報告を個別に確認し、可能な限り早く対応します。

**ご連絡ください。**
できるかぎり早く回答いたします。

お問い合わせ

### サイトポリシー

本行動規範は、個々のサイトポリシーと共に機能します。サイトやチャットルームは、特にオフトピック/オントピックに関して、ここで許可されているものよりも厳しいポリシーを採用する場合もあります。

### ユーザー名とプロフィール

ユーザーがプロフィールで自分自身を表現することは奨励されていますが、それらも行動規範及びすべてのポリシーの対象となります。

Comment: ご投稿本当にありがとうございます！現在確認していることがいくつかありますので、おそれいりますが少しだけお時間をいただけますでしょうか。

Comment: @aki こちらまだ翻訳してはいけませんか？　行動規範に誘導しづらくなっているので和訳してしまいたいです。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、みなさん、8月から待ち続け、11月になった今も待機状態で大変申し訳なく思います。一時的となる可能性もあるようなのですが本投稿を和訳してまいりますので改善等できる箇所を見つけられた方はどうぞご編集くださいませ‍♀️。

Comment: 単語の置き換えなど本当にありがとうございます！Traducir にて緑の thumbs-up マークを押せる方はよろしくお願いいたします！[こちら](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/11823)が正しい string なのかなどはサイトに反映されてから確認できるかと