# 行動規範の和訳文（2018年−2023年）

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, 行動規範

2018年8月13日から2023年4月頃まで、スタック・オーバーフローにおいて表示されていた行動規範の和訳文が、現在はサイト上で[見えなくなってしまっています](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3900/14055)。モデレーションを行う際などに日本語で参照いただけるように、以下にその和訳文を記載いたします。新しい行動規範の和訳文がサイト上に反映されるまで、ある程度の時間を要する見込みですが、それまではこちらをご活用いただければ幸いです。確認等に時間がかかってしまい大変申し訳ありませんが何卒よろしくお願い致します。

---

## 行動規範

**この行動規範は、親切に協力し合える、そしてお互いを尊重することができるコミュニティを形成するためのものです。**

質問をするためにこのサイトを訪れた人も、知識を惜しみなく共有しに来たという人も、専門知識やアイデンティティに関わらず全ての人が温かく迎えられ参加できるコミュニティを共に作ろうではありませんか。

私たちは本行動規範を遵守し、これからも改善して行くことに全力を尽くします。スタック・オーバーフロー 及び Stack Exchange ネットワーク全てのサイトに本行動規範は適用され、チーム、モデレーター、そして Q&A サイトやチャットルームに投稿する全てのユーザーが含まれます。

### 私たちが期待すること

**助けを求めてここに来た場合には、他の人があなたを手助けしやすいよう気を配りましょう。**
ガイドラインに従いましょう。そして私たちのコミュニティはボランティアによって可能となり存在していることを忘れないでおきましょう。

**誰かを助けるためにここに来た場合には、辛抱強くなり、そして全ての人を温かく迎えるようにしましょう。**
新しいユーザーはスタック・オーバーフローのルールや仕組みをよく知らないかもしれません。サイトに慣れるまで、優しく辛抱強く見守ってあげましょう。

**フィードバックをする時には明確で建設的に、そしてフィードバックを受ける時にはオープンマインドを心がけましょう。**
編集やコメント、提案はコミュニティの健全な一面なのです。

**親切でフレンドリーな態度を心がけましょう。**
皮肉な言葉は避け、冗談にも気をつけてください。オンライン上ではそれらのトーンを解釈し辛いものです。フレンドリーな態度を保ち辛い場合は一度そこから離れて心を切り替え、次に進んでください。

### 容認できない行為

けなす言動や敵意のある言葉は許されません。
意図しなくても他の人にはマイナスの影響を与えてしまいます。

❌ : 好ましくない
⭕️ : 好ましい！

❌「ググればそんな簡単なことはすぐにわかるでしょ。」
⭕️「これは Invariance と Covariance と呼ばれています。もしグーグル検索をすればチュートリアルを見つけることができるようですし、おそらくここで私たちが説明するよりもそちらの方がわかりやすいでしょう。」

❌「もし私の質問を普通に読んでくれてたら、重複ではないってことにすぐに気付くでしょ」
⭕️「重複しているようには見えません。私の質問はセメント板について聞いていて、あなたがリンクくださったのはドライウォールについてのようです。」

❌「一体どこの国の言葉を話してるんだ？さっぱりわからん。」
⭕️「あなたの質問を理解するのに少し時間がかかっています。システムインストレーションの後にどのようにして swap を追加すればよいのかという質問のように見受けられますが、正しいでしょうか？」

❌「助けを求めてここにやってきたんだ。私の質問を勝手に編集されるためではない。」
⭕️「ありがとうございます。編集いただいたようですが、私の意図とは少しずれているようです。明確にするため、あなたがしてくださった編集は一度削除させていただき私の質問をアップデートしました。」

**個人に対する批評は許されません。**
投稿者ではなく投稿内容に焦点を当ててください。内容に対する批評であっても個人へのあてつけと取れる表現（手抜きなど）も含みます。

**偏見は許されません。**
人種や性別、性的指向、宗教などに基づき個人やグループを攻撃するような言葉は許されません。これらはいくつかの例であり、判別がつきかねる言葉自体許されません。

**嫌がらせは許されません。**
以下を含みますがこれらに限定されるわけではありません：いじめ、威嚇、乱暴な言葉、直接的または間接的な脅し、性的な暗示を含むもの、不適切な接触パターン、長期間にわたる議論の混乱など。